# Changing Samba port doesn't work

Tags: samba, port, arch-linux

I want to change the Samba default ports for testing. I tried adding "samba ports = 1445" to the samba config, but now I can't connect to it at all! I also tried adding -p 1445 to the samba start script. Windows says the network path cannot be found when trying to map it.

I am using ArkOS (modified version of ArchLinux for ARM) and Samba 4.1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any errors when you start samba?

Is the ArkOS server behind a firewall? Run nmap to be sure the port is open:

```
nmap -p 1445 localhost
```

Comment: ArkOS apparently has a firewall and it was added in the most recent release, so now it works once I added the port via iptables! :3